# JSON hierarchies encoding and event-capture

Tags: json

Consider the following JSON structure:

```
{'100': {'Time': '02:00:00', 'Group': 'A', 'Similar events': [101, 102, 104, 120],
'101': {'Time': '02:01:00', 'Group': 'B', 'Similar events': [100, 103, 105, 111],
'102': {'Time': '04:00:00', 'Group': 'A', 'Similar events': [104, 100, 107, 121]}
```

The top-level keys (e.g. `'100'`, `'101'`, etc.) are unique identifiers. I have come to find this is *not* the ideal way to store JSON (attempting to load this structure - with many more events - crashed my PC).

After some digging, I believe this is the proper way (or, at least, a much more canonical way) of encoding these data in JSON:

```
{'Time': [{'100': '02:00:00'},
          {'101': '02:01:00'},
          {'102': '04:00:00'}],

'Group': [{'100': 'A'},
          {'101': 'B'}, 
          {'102': 'A'}],

'Similar events': [{'100': [101, 102, 104, 120]},
                   {'101': [100, 103, 105, 111]},
                   {'102': [104, 100, 107, 121]}]}
```

My machine is able to handle much better this last attempt. Why does my former method of using unique events as (what I think are) individual "rows" cause so much trouble? My gut tells me each "column" or key within each record in the former try becomes a new field since it's found under a unique identifier (a unique key).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without more details such as the total size of your data, the amount of memory on your computer, the software you're using and the specific operations your're trying to do but it may be that the working set of the second representation is smaller for your problem.

Comment: The size of the data aren't an issue, I don't think. I believe the issue is related to the former approach and how it effectively creates *n* * *k* different fields because of the ID-at-the-top-level storage mechanism. It's like creating *n* * *k* columns in a CSV, instead of *k* (where *k* is the number of unique fields to capture), if you follow me.

Comment: @blacksite Your second approach is the same amount of fields just more rows than columns. This is not an inherent problem, nothing about one of this 2 approaches makes it more proper than the other. If the later works for you it's because of some specific way you use it.

Comment: @Oleg I'm trying to load these data into Tableau, and the way Tableau's handling the first approach is by creating that many different columns... I'm currently converting this stuff to a sort-of star schema in the interim while I figure this out.

Comment: @blacksite Try putting the eventid inside and making it an array of events.